# How can thermal electrical noise be uncorrelated yet appearing at a certain frequency?

Tags: noise, signal, signal-processing

Say we look at the thermal noise spectrum of an ideal resistor. Now we know it will behave like  $$ \langle U^2 \rangle = 4 \, k_B \, T  \,R \,\Delta f $$

We also know that two subsequent voltages are uncorrelated:
$$
\langle U(t) U(t+\tau)\rangle = c\, \delta(\tau) 
$$
where c is a proportional constant.

Now my question is: How are these two relations compatible with each other? Phrased in words of the experimentalist, what causes a certain \$ U^2 \$ to appear at frequency bin \$f\$? Shouldn't it have *some* component \$ ~\propto e^{iwt} \$?

Comment: Ask yourself how a delta function is defined to have some power at every frequency. The argument for thermal noise is the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you convolve your U(t) with \$e^{i\omega t}\$ then you'll typically get a non-zero result. This means there *is* typically some component at \$\omega\$.

Note that if you convolve a delta function \$\delta (t)\$ with \$e^{i\omega t}\$, you'll also get a non-zero result, for all values of \$\omega\$.

The difference between noise and a delta function is the variance in the measured power. With a delta function, the spectrum is flat and consistent. With noise, the spectrum is only flat and consistent after sufficient averaging of multiple convolution results.

Answer (score 0):

Since an ideal resistor has no memory elements (like capacitor or inductor), the thermal noise generated will not see any filtering element. Consequently, the noise spectrum can be expected to be flat at all frequencies. (Neglecting the quantum mechanical effects which become important at high frequencies where the spectrum begins to fall with frequency.)

By the same argument, since ideal resistor has no memory element, the noise current at a later time can have no dependency on the past current values. This implies the current at any one instant will be totally uncorrelated with current at any other instant. Hence, the correlation exists only at \$t = 0\$, and resulting autocorrelation is a delta function.
In general, correlation in time domain implies filtered noise spectrum in frequency domain, called colored/shaped noise.
Mathematically, the power spectral density is Fourier transform of autocorrelation function. Basic uncertainty principle says that, bigger spread in frequency domain results in narrower time response and vice-versa. Thus, a flat response in frequency domain causes the time response to have no time spread at all, giving it the impulse shape.

Answer (score 0):

The thermal noise of an ideal resistor can be considered to be white, and thus has a constant power spectral density of \$\frac{N_0}{2}\$. This is known as the *double-sided* power spectral density.

Your mistake comes from the fact that the expression of the variance, or noise power, is a result of integrating across a certain double-sided bandwidth \$B\$. It is not the value contained at each frequency. More specifically, the noise power is actually what is observed through some type of filter or system having a frequency response \$H(f)\$ and is given by

$$\sigma^2 = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{N_0}{2}|H(f)|^2df$$

The output from an ideal unity lowpass or bandpass filter over a double-sided bandwidth \$B\$ is then

$$\sigma^2 = \int_{-B}^{B}\frac{N_0}{2}|H(f)|^2df = N_0B$$

This is the nice expression we see all the time!

We can approach this from the stochastic process point of view and consider an input process \$X(t)\$ to be wide-sense-stationary (WSS) with a power spectral density \$S_X(f) = \frac{N_0}{2}\$. When the input is applied to a filter or system having frequency response \$H(f)\$, the output power spectral density \$S_Y(f)\$ is given by

$$S_Y(f) = S_X(f)|H(f)|^2 = \frac{N_0}{2}|H(f)|^2$$

The **Wiener-Khinchin Theorem** states that given a WSS process, **the Fourier transform of its autocorrelation is the power spectral density**. This also means that given the power spectral density, we can find the autocorrelation function by taking the inverse Fourier transform and so

$$R_Y(\tau) = \mathcal{F}^{-1}({S_Y(f)}) $$

Thus, for an ideal unity lowpass or bandpass filter

$$R_Y(\tau) = \mathcal{F}^{-1}({S_Y(f)}) = \frac{N_0}{2}\delta(\tau)$$

Which is your second expression. So the expression for the variance (power) and the autocorrelation are not at odds at all.